# Ruby on Rails, problema con base de datos al mostrar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Quiero mostrar los datos de mi base de datos de rails en la pagina.

He conseguido que aparezca toda la base de datos, toda la informacion. Pero lo que quiero es, que solo una columna aparezca, en este caso la informacion de nombre. Que me haga un listado de los nombres que tengo en la BD.

En el Index de mi controlador:

```
< @f.each do |f| %>
    <%= Terminal.all
<% end %>
```

En el mismo controlador:

```
def index
    @f = Terminal.all
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Médoto 1: Accesando al campo deseado en cada registro

Si en tu controlador estás asignando a `@f` todos los registros que deseas mostrar

```
#/app/controllers/terminals_controller.rb    
@f = Terminal.all
```

Entonces para mostrar un solo campo, en este caso nombre, debes iterar sobre todos los registros que tiene la variable `@f` con el método `.each` y para cada registro mostrar el campo de interés:

```
#/app/views/terminals/index.html.erb
<% @f.each do |f| %>
  <%= f.nombre %><br>
<% end %>
```

### Médoto 2: Usando pluck

En Rails 3.2 o superior, otra forma sería usando `.pluck`, que solo cargaría la columna que le indiques

```
#/app/controllers/terminals_controller.rb
@f2 = Human.pluck(:name)
```

Y para mostrar en la vista sería algo así:

```
#/app/views/terminals/index.html.erb
<% @f2.each do |f| %>
  <%= f %><br>
<% end %>
```

Aquí la link para la documentación de [pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck).

Comment: `pluck` no funciona solo en Rails 3.2, también en 4.x y 5.x, así que creo está de más la acotación.

Comment: @AlterLagos claro, quería decir que desde Rails 3.2 en adelante. Gracias por la observación.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me has ayudado!!

Answer (score 0):

Primero que todo según el código que publicaste, hay algunos errores de sintaxis, los voy a corregir antes de darte posibles soluciones a los que pides.

Primero:

`<% @f.each do |f| %>
    <%= Terminal.all %>
<% end %>`

Segundo: si ya definiste en el controlador que `@f= Terminal.all` no deberías repetirlo en la vista, por lo tanto quedaría

`<% @f.each do |f| %>
    <%= f %>
<% end %>`

Pasando a las solución del problema, podrías lograrlo de 2 formas

1. En el controlador:

   `def index
       @f = Terminal.all.select(:name)
   end`

   En la vista:

   `<% @f.each do |f| %>
       <%= f %>
   <% end %>`
2. En el controlador:

   `def index
       @f = Terminal.all
   end`

   En la vista:

   `<% @f.each do |f| %>
       <%= f %>
   <% end %>`

Anotación: te doy una respuesta basado en el código que publicaste, igual hay mejores maneras de estructurar la aplicación,de acuerdo a la arquitectura MVC.

Comment: Tu segunda forma, según lo que describes, mostraría algo como `#<Terminal:0x00000006ab85f0>` en la vista. Creo que no es lo que querías explicar.

Comment: Muchas gracias a ti tambien, pero he usado el comentarioa anterior! Pero te lo agradezco!